# ANSI SQL:2008: Are TRUNCATE or TRUNC a SQL Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, truncate, ansi-sql

ANSI SQL:2008: Are TRUNCATE or TRUNC a SQL Function?
Where can I find the ANSI SQL:2008?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! to get good answer you will need to improve your question. what did you do to find the answer ? please read how to ask question in Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

[TRUNCATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_%28SQL%29) "was officially introduced in the SQL:2008 standard."

[SQL:2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) "is not freely available. The whole standard may be purchased from the ISO as ISO/IEC 9075(1-4,9-11,13,14):2008."

O'Reilly *SQL in a Nutshell* (ISBN-10: 0596518846, ISBN-13: 978-0596518844) lists TRUNC() as a "Platform-specific extension."

Comment: But the article refers to the statement (command). I want to know if there is a function with the same name.

Comment: Can you provide an example usage of either or both names?

Comment: Yes, I can. Here in this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm

Comment: Got it - if you trust the folks at O'Reilly, I'd guess it's not ANSI.

Comment: You might edit the title of the Q to be more along the lines of what you're after. For example: "Is the TRUNC function in Oracle part of the ANSI SQL:2008 standard"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-truncate.html), yes, this is a standard command.  The family of standards documents are [linked to from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008), but IMHO these are not very usable in their raw form.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your awser PaulProgrammer. But I want to know if there is a function with the same name.